# git add in Xcode generates com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain error -70

Tags: xcode, git

I can 100% reproduce this - if I clone a repository, drag and drop a couple of files into the cloned directory then add them to the Xcode project, then Xcode will correctly put an A status flag next to them.
But then if I select the new files and do Source Control/Commit Selected Files I get this error:

"The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErroDomain error -70).

Has anybody else seen this or know what the problem is?

Comment: WHy have you down marked this? Do you know the answer then? Well speak up!!! I tried googling for this error message but there's no results. So why exactly have you down marked this. Tell Me

Comment: I'm still waiting for an explanation for the down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue too. No idea what is causing the problem.

If you perform SourceControl->UpdateSelectedFiles the issue goes away.

Comment: I'm still waiting for an explanation on why my original question was down voted, and now somebody has down voted this too! If you're the same person then tell us both why the down votes? THis is a valid question, if you know the answer then tell us you silent coward. Otherwise explain the down votes.

Comment: Maybe someone has something against beans and Daves...who knows.  I put up the fix in case someone else came here with the same problem--Goggling the error brings one here.  It drove me nuts and took forever to figure out.  Hopefully my answer will save someone some time.

Answer (score 3):

please check your svn authentication has been done properly.
you can check setting in xcode > preferences > accounts > repositories there is not retry authentication warning in particular repository in which you are trying to commit

Answer (score 0):

check your setting to xcode > preferences > accounts > repogitories

Answer (score 0):

this works for me! xcode -> preferences -> accounts -> remove gitAccount